# Specifying file prerequisites for Rake task

Tags: ruby, rake, rake-task, rakefile

I've got a helper class that scans my entire project directory and collects a list of source files and the corresponding (target) object files. The dependencies on the compile task is defined after scanning the source directory as shown below.

```
CLEAN.include(FileList[obj_dir + '**/*.o'])
CLOBBER.include(FileList[exe_dir + '**/*.exe'])

$proj = DirectoryParser.new(src_dir)

$proj.source_files.each do |source_file|
  file source_file.obj_file do
    sh "gcc -c ..."
  end
end

$proj.obj_files.each do |obj_file|
  task :compile => obj_file
end

task :compile do
end
```

Since `$proj` is global, the DirectoryParser.new() is invoked when any of the tasks are called including `clean` and `clobber`. This makes the `clean` and `clobber` tasks slow and that is not desirable.

To get around the problem I moved all the generation of File dependencies into the default task. This makes my `clean` and `clobber` tasks fast, however, I can't call my compile or link tasks independently now.

```
CLEAN.include(FileList[obj_dir + '**/*.o'])
CLOBBER.include(FileList[exe_dir + '**/*.exe'])

task :compile => $proj.source_files do   # Throws error!
end

task :default => do
  $proj = DirectoryParser.new(src_dir)

  $proj.source_files.each do |source_file|
    file source_file.obj_file do
      sh "gcc -c ..."
    end
  end

  $proj.obj_files.each do |obj_file|
    task :compile => obj_file
  end

  ... compile
  ... link
  ... execute
end
```

How do I get around this problem? I am sure someone has previously encountered a similar problem. I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: I've decided to keep the same solution above at the cost of the `clean` and `clobber` tasks taking a bit longer than I'd like. Unless someone comes up with a better solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get around this problem elegantly by using the Singleton design pattern and moving away from using Rake file/task dependencies completely. DirectoryParser is now a singleton class (by mixing in Ruby's built-in 'singleton' library)

```
CLEAN.include(FileList[obj_dir + '**/*.o'])
CLOBBER.include(FileList[exe_dir + '**/*.exe'])

task :compile do
  $proj = DirectoryParser.instance
  $proj.source_files.each do |source_file|
      sh "gcc -c ..." unless uptodate?(obj_file, source_file)
  end
end

task :link do
  $proj = DirectoryParser.instance
  ...
end
```

Now my clean/clobber tasks are fast and I can still call compile/link tasks independently.

Answer (score 3):

You could try a two step approach.

Create a new task `generate_dependencies`.
This task builds a (static) rake file with your dependencies and actions.

This generated rakefile can be loaded in your rake file.

Some sample code (untested):

```
GENERATED = 'generated_dependencies.rb'

task :generate_dependencies do
  $proj = DirectoryParser.new(src_dir)

  File.open(GENERATED, 'w') do |f|
    $proj.source_files.each do |source_file|
      f << <<-code
      file #{source_file.obj_file} do
        sh "gcc -c " #etc.
      end
      code
    end

    $proj.obj_files.each do |obj_file|
      f << "task :compile => #{obj_file}"
    end

    #~ ... compile
    #~ ... link
    #~ ... execute
  end
end

require GENERATED
```

Now you have two steps:

1. create an empty 'generated_dependencies.rb' (so you get no error when you call the script the first time)
2. call `rake generate_dependencies`
3. Check the generated file - if it's not good, change the generator ;)
4. call `rake compile` or `rake link` (or `rake` if you want to use the default task) ... - the dependencies are defined in the generated file.

   - When something changes (new files), continue from step 2.
   - If the structure stays the same (no new files, only code changes) you need only step 4.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Does that mean 'rake generate_dependencies' and 'rake install' has to be called manually by the user? That places an unnecessary burden on the user and I don't really want that. I want that to happen transparently as far as the user is concerned.

Comment: I think not. I changed my answer a bit. You may define the default as you want (e.g. the sequence compile, link and execute). Before you run the default, you must run once `rake generate_dependencies`. The only problem you have: If the structure changes (new source codes...) anyone must call `rake generate_dependencies` to update the dependecies. I tried to get a 'real' solution, but I ran into problems - in the same time I had the idea with this two step solution. Not really a full solution, but sometimes it better to have a half solution then no solution.

Comment: Thanks for the response again. Running `generate_dependencies` manually is not what I am after, as it will place a burden on the user to remember things and from experience that can be very error-prone. The work-around I've used works, but the only drawback is that you can't call compile/link tasks independently (you have to call `rake` which invokes the default task).

Comment: ...er, there are a couple others as well that I just saw. I've suggested an edit for your consideration. Also, to make sure the file exists, you can `touch GENERATED` (the method exists, and if you're not sure you can always `sh "touch #{GENERATED}"`)